# Is there an equivalent of latex \newcommand in mediawiki

Tags: latex, mediawiki

I want to create a command in mediawiki. For example, in latex I can do

```
 \newcommand{\concept}{\textbf}
```

Is it possible to create an alias for `'''foo'''` and so on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MediaWiki uses [templates](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates) for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Like Roger said , you can create templates ,create a page called 'template:foo' with content '''foo''' 
then you can insert it to where ever you wanted by placing {{foo}}.

and when you change the content of the page template:foo all other pages where {{foo}} is placed will also change accordingly.

you can also insert it by placing {{subst:foo}} this will substitute the content of the template to that place. but when you change the template page later , it won't reflect here. :)